# If an element is 0 then add class to closest div

Tags: element

Below script works but its adding 'not' class to all the parent divs. I want the script to add class to only the parent where the 'UL' is missing. below is my code

```
<div class="accordion">
  <div class="accordion-panel"><div class="related-items-list-v2">
    <ul><li>hello</li></ul>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="accordion-panel">
  <div class="related-items-list-v2"></div>
</div>
```

Script

```
if ($('.accordion-panel ul').length > 0){
     $('.accordion-panel').addClass('not');
    }
```

Comment: `$('.accordion-panel').addClass('not');` It's doing what it's supposed to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(".accordion-panel").each(function() {
    if($(this).find("ul").length == 0) {
        $(this).addClass("not");
    }
})
```

Comment: Thanks for quick responce. But 'not' class should only get add for the parent where UL is missing. this code adding class for both parents. please help